# Keeping leading zero from a string VBScript ASP Classic

Tags: vbscript

I have a string that contains letters and numbers. The string is something like this "PST025", "PST026", etc...

What I'm trying to do is take the last string from a table and create the next number. So if the last string is "PST026", I need to create a new string "PST027".

I have the following code:

```
strAsset = rsStandards("asset") 
nextAsset = CStr((Mid(strAsset,4,3)))
nextAsset = nextAsset + 1
```

The problem is that "nextAsset' gives me "27" instead of "027". I need to keep the leading 1 in there.

Any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
strAsset = rsStandards("asset") 
nextAsset = Mid(strAsset, 4, 3)
nextAsset = CInt(nextAsset) + 1   ' it would be smart to should check IsNumeric() here
nextAsset = Left(strAsset, 3) & Right("00" & nextAsset, 3)
```

Comment: it's giving me the following error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'Left'"

Comment: @Brasciole Whoops, `Left()` only takes 2 parameters. Try again.

Comment: Same error? I don't think so, the `Left()` call is fine now.